# Looking for a way to handle/approach PHP OOP websites

Tags: php, oop

I'm not new to PHP or programming at all. But recently I was thinking about website programming in PHP and how easier it was before the OOP. Anyway, I prefer OOP than the old procedural style. 
I want to implement a website but it seems I always have to use a global or a static variables. And I'm starting to wonder, how can I do it without those?

Anyway, what I'm talking about is having a class for each "component" of the website.
For example if it was an url shortener website it would be: links, members, database.

What I'm talking about is way more complicated, at least 8 classes.
Anyway, my current approach is the following:

```
$database = new Database(...);
$links = new Links($db);
$users = new Users($db);
```

Anyway, for example I want to get all the links a user posted by its ID, I need to use both links and both users components.

Is there any other way I could do this? Any other approach? except passing them as constructor parameters.

Comment: I think it's alright this way as well. What bothers you if you use it this way?

Comment: If you don't want to pass them as constructor arguments, you can simply declare an object of type User inside the required function of class Link. And then use the User object there.

Comment: While having many classes, lets say 8 I need to always set them in a specific order so for example users would be able to go into links, but after that I want to use lets say links in users it's really devastating. (Hope you understood)

Comment: Yes, i get your point. I do it the same way. It frustrates me too. But i think, except the order, technically there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: And if I would create an array and create all of those objects inside him, then pass the array into each object, is it possible?

Comment: I think it's possible, but i would need to see a code sample to be sure of what you are asking.

Comment: $objects = array(
        "links" => new Links();
        ...
    );
    foreach($objects as $o)
        $o.passObjects($objects);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have the following components:

1. Business objects, which model and express one particular "thing" in your app:

   ```
   class Link { ... }
   class User { ... }
   ```

   These don't "do" anything, they're just there to formalise your data structures. These objects have getter and setter methods to get and set individual attributes, which are also validated there:

   ```
   public function setUrl($url) {
       if (!/* validate the URL here*/) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("$url is not a valid URL");
       }
       $this->url = $url;
   }
   ```

   Minimum required data is part of the constructor. This ensures your data integrity application-wide. It allows you to assert that when you have an instance of `Link`, the data expressed by it is minimum valid data for a link.
2. A database link. Only the bare necessary thing to connect to a database, nothing more, nothing less. A raw `PDO` or `mysqli` object will do just fine.
3. A data-object mapper, which takes a database link and knows how to store business objects in the database and how to retrieve them:

   ```
   class LinkStorage {

       protected $db;

       public function __construct(PDO $db) {
           $this->db = $db;
       }

   }
   ```

   This class has all the various methods of how to retrieve things from your database:

   ```
   public function getById($id) {
       $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = :id');
       $stmt->execute(compact('id'));

       if (!$data = $stmt->fetch()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Record with id $id does not exist");
       }

       return new Link($data['url']);
   }
   ```

   You can have all sorts of different queries encapsulated this way, e.g.:

   ```
   /**
    * Returns all links by a particular user.
    * @param User $user
    * @return Link[]
    */
   public function getAllFromUser(User $user) {
       ...
   }
   ```

The usage is then simple:

```
$db          = new PDO(...);
$linkStorage = new LinkStorage($db);
$userStorage = new UserStorage($db);

$user  = $userStorage->getById($id);
$links = $linkStorage->getAllFromUser($user);
```

This kind of code would then be encapsulated in a service class, which holds all the possible "actions" you can do in your app. `registerUser(array $data)`, `getLinksOfUser($id)`, `newLinkFromPostData(array $data)` etc.

What I've just described is basically the *model* portion of an MVC-style application. The other two parts would be controllers which call the service methods, and views which output data retrieved from service methods. This approach keeps responsibilities separate and isolated and allows you to put higher-level logic and functionality together like building blocks. Business objects are the lowest building block, their structure needs to be solid and well defined for the rest to work. Data-object mappers just concern themselves with putting those objects into the database and getting them back out again. Services then put all this together in various complex ways and make things happen.

You shouldn't have any cyclic dependencies with this, as responsibilities are well separated. Your individual dependencies may still be somewhat complex. If it becomes too cumbersome to instantiate classes, you'll want to look into Factories:

```
$factory = new Factory;
$userStorage = $factory->newUserStorage();
```

All the complexity of instantiation is encapsulated in this factory. One step further are dependency injection containers, who you can configure in, for example, an XML file to specify which class depends on what, and then the DI container will take care of it for you.

Comment: I really like this idea and love the effort you put into writing all of this. Anyway, when you're saying "service" class, what do you mean? can you give an example?

Comment: I did. A service class has methods like `LinksService::createFromArrayForUser($userId, array $linkData)`. It's the next complex step above talking to the database. The business objects don't *do* anything, the data-object mappers only negotiate between business objects and the database, services then are the place to take in some form of data and make something happen with it. Services are your "actions". It contains the code for things like *registering a new user and sending a confirmation email*. That's a complex action comprised of several individual steps.

Comment: Alright, and are the services are accessed in a static way in your approach? (like in the example you just stated)

Comment: No, (virtually) nothing is ever accessed statically. :) That was just a notational convention.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for the approach, it's perfect. And one last thing, about the injection using XML files, may you have an example for this?

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking about website programming in PHP and how easier it was
> before the OOP

Well, stick to procedural then. If it is easier to write a well written website in a procedural or functional way then opposed to the ojbect-oriented way. Stick ti what you are used to. OO isn't better then functional. It's just a different approach.

### the public void main() in php

In the lanuage Java every piece of software we write has a single entry point. The `public void main()` method. This method fires up the entire application and passes in the arguments provided on startup. It is also the only exit point in the application. the application ends in this method (unless it crashes).

In php, there is no single entry point. We have a bunch of files that run some scripts that do some more stuff and then somewhere along the line another script decides to return stuff and die();

### Dependency injection and how IoC libraries can help

When using dependency injection, it becomes a real pain in the a$$ when creating objects and passing arround the correct instance of a class. We start solving this problem with ugly solutions: Singleton, globals, statics, ... Making our software more and more tightly coupled and harder to maintain.

Inversion of Control can help here. there are some really greate [articles](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-huh--net-26903) on the webz.

Comment: PHP *does* very well have a single entry point: the first line in the file that you execute. From there it's all just includes and autoloads, not much different from Java really.

Comment: it's actually the first line of the file the user asked ( unless you rewrite all files using mod_Rewrite or ...). Where as in Java, you can't just start in the beginnin of a file you want

Comment: My main programming language is Java that's the reason I want to stick to OOP, I love the data structure. Anyway, thank you for the articles.

Comment: If you're simply exposing arbitrary library files publicly, that's not PHP's fault. :) A "user" shouldn't simply be able to request some arbitrary file they're not allowed to request. Yes, PHP's default structure makes that easy... But I can also simply "execute" any arbitrary Java class if I wanted to. (Not that that would do anything useful, typically, but that's the same as in PHP.)

Comment: you could allow the user to request different files. nothing wrong with that. index.php and admin.php for instance. And no, you can't just execute any arbitrary Java class (you can if you have the code, but not if a Java app is given to you).

Answer (score -1):

You can use autoloading in PHP for a better solution:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php