# Instantiate the db connection in a parent class then its children classes can inherit from it?

Tags: php, inheritance, pdo, multiple-inheritance

Is it a good idea to instantiate the db connection in a **parent** class then its children classes can **inherit** by it?

For instance, this is my core model,

```
class CoreModel
{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Construct database connection data.
        $this->connection = new Database(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $this->connection->connect();
    }

}
```

then I have these classes that extend from `CoreModel`,

```
class Article extends CoreModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Image extends CoreModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Controller extends CoreModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Does it cause the db connection to be made endless times? so that would be **3** db connections in my case above?

If this is a bad idea, what is the base way to instantiate the db connection **just once** so that all the classes can depend on it?

**EDIT:**

```
$connection = new Database(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$connection->connect();

$controller = new Controller($connection);
$article = new Article($connection);

class Article {

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(Database $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably would find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a bad idea. The constructor code will be executed individually for each child, you'll have multiple database connections in the end. Beyond that, it's a bad idea to hardcode a certain class with a specific database connection. You should be [*dependency injecting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) the database connection into the constructor:

```
class Article {

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(Database $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

}
```

Though it also seems like a bad idea to have a "model class" with direct database access. You should peruse this question: [Looking for a way to handle/approach PHP OOP websites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24886229/476)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean that I should do it in the method just as in my edit above?

Comment: also what does it for to have a prefix `Database` in `public function __construct(Database $connection){...}`

Comment: also what do you mean `hardcode a certain class with a specific database connection.` in `Beyond that, it's a bad idea to hardcode a certain class with a specific database connection.`?

Comment: No, you instantiate the `$connection` outside of `Article`, then pass it to `Article` when you construct it: `new Article($connection)`. And the `Database` in the function signature is a *type hint*, requiring a `Database` object.

Comment: I mean you're making your code inflexible by instantiating a database connection in its constructor. Please read [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/), then read the other Q&A linked to in the question, then read up on *dependency injection*. It's not hard really, but all the thinking and reasoning can't be explained in one comment.